# Follow up to "I would like to blow a whistle but don't want to face retaliation"

Tags: fraud, regulations

I asked the question a couple weeks ago:

[I would like to blow a whistle but don't want to face retaliation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/i-would-like-to-blow-a-whistle-but-dont-want-to-face-retaliation)

The advice that was given was to contact an attorney who would typically represent the other side.

I did this, and the attorney told me, "hey I can't get involved in this.  If the people in my circles find out that I was involved in getting one of our own in trouble, nobody will want to work with me."   He gave me the name of some other firms, but told me that they would probably say the same thing.  This was precisely the "conflict of interest" to which I was referring.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you're leaving out some relevant facts.  You contacted an attorney at a legal practice?  Then who is he referring to as "one of our own?"  Are you whistleblowing on a legal bar or a law firm?

Comment: The bad behavior I'm interested in reporting is best done with a knowledgeable lawyer.  (It involves setting up chains of holding companies and such.)  It's lucrative business, so the handful of lawyers who practice in this area are working for the companies who do this very thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to get referred to qualified legal counsel willing to represent you from any or all of the following sources:

- The legal department of the SEC
- Your state Attorney General's office
- Your local U.S. Attorney's office

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what we're missing from the situation: I would **contact the Bar association** in any state that may have jurisdiction in the matter.  They all have referral services, and if you explain that you have been denied service by licensed attorneys for "reputational" risk [I would hope](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/915/10) that the Bar would take an exceptional interest in seeing that you find competent representation.  Ensuring accessibility to legal counsel is, after all, one of the supposed foundations of the legal profession and its cartel.

If you are still unable to find a competent lawyer through the Bar please share the details of your efforts and their results, because that would be a fascinating and eye-opening situation!  (And, in such a case, there would be some more extreme measures available to you.  E.g., I imagine if you fully documented your efforts then you could petition a court to *compel* one of its officers to serve as your legal council.)

Comment: After some research (using the online ACMS) I was able to find a lawyer who had filed a complaint against a company who was involved in this business.  I called him, and he seems to be quite knowledgeable, so hopefully I'm all set.

Comment: @A.S. - Nice work!  Good luck.